# JQuery .ajax enters Success before calling page finishes

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I've got the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
        $("#AddMaps").submit(function(){

            var $form = $('#AddMaps');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $form.attr( 'action' ),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    // Set up Loading Image and disable submit button
                    $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    // Successful Request; do something
                    $('#ajax-panel').empty();
                    if (data.response != "Success"){
                        $('#ajax-panel').append('Error Occurred' + data.response);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#ajax-panel').append('File(s) Uploaded');
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    // Failed Request; Freak out
                    $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
                }
            });
        });
        });



        </script>

        <form id="AddMaps" action="test_multiple.php">
            <fieldset>
            <label for="server">Select a Server:</label>
            <select name="server" id="server">
        <option value="1">Server 1</option>
        <option value="2">Server 2</option>
        <option value="3">Server 3</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload">
            <div id="ajax-panel"></div>
        </form>
```

The problem I am having, is that the ajax call is entering the success function long before the call to test_multiple.php completes. test_multiple is doing a lot of back end work and if I call it directly the page takes approximately 15 seconds to load. Using this, it is reporting that it completes instantly, even though I can see the work in the backend isn't done yet.

Why does it enter success right away? How do I stop it from doing so?

Additionally, Firebug is reporting an aborted POST request to test_multiple but a successful GET request to test_multiple.

Comment: is this a file upload?... file upload can't be done via ajax without the help of some flash as far as I know ...

Comment: Well, it can, if you create a hidden iframe and submit the form to that.

include 

complete:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) { $('#ajax-panel').append('Request Complete'); }

But I think it's just returning a failed (successfully) request.  You can check the second parameter of success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) for the status and you can check the request object for more data regarding the request.

Comment: Its not an upload, but it is transferring a set of files between servers on the back end. Nothing is coming from the user's computer though. It is functioning, its just that the success function is called before it completes the transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably happening because your form is submitting the normal way. You need to `return false` at the end of your submit handler to prevent the form from redirecting to the specified 'action', thus allowing the XHR request to finish.

> Additionally, Firebug is reporting an
>   aborted POST request to test_multiple
>   but a successful GET request to
>   test_multiple.

The form tag in your markup has no 'method' attribute set, so it defaults to GET. This is evidence that your form is being submitted the normal way. The aborted POST is probably because the XHR request did not get a chance to finish before the server received the normal HTTP GET request and starting sending output.

Comment: I've added the `return false` at the end of the submit handler, but now it is jumping to the error handler. The calling script still completes successfully (checked in the backend), but JQuery is saying it didn't. 

I also added `method="POST"` (d'oh!). Firebug is still showing this POST request aborted, but as expected it is not reverting to GET. As mentioned above though, the request does actually complete.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it answers the question about why I was entering Jquery's success method. I'll open a new question about Firebug and the aborted POST. Thanks you.